# In RXJS, how do I force re-execution of an Observable created with bindNodeCallback using retryWhen?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I have a `Subject` that receives objects and then makes a call to a function that I have wrapped with `bindNodeCallback`. I'd like to retry execution of that function, using `retryWhen`, if it fails due to an error or if the result comes back false.

I've tried a few different approaches but haven't been successful at getting the bound function to fire off again.

I have a [codesandbox setup here](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-wave-u5bhx?file=/src/index.ts).

```js
function fakeSend(
  task: string,
  cb: (err: Error | null, result?: boolean) => void
) {
  console.log("fakesend", task);

  setTimeout(() => {
    const hasError = Math.random() < 0.5;
    const res = Math.random() < 0.5;
    console.log(hasError ? "hasError" : `responding with ${res}`);
    if (hasError) {
      return cb(new Error("error"));
    }
    return cb(null, res);
  }, 100);
}

const boundSend = bindNodeCallback(fakeSend);
const subject = new Subject<string>();

subject.subscribe(
  (task) => {
    boundSend(task)
      .pipe(
        tap((status) => {
          if (!status) {
            throw new Error("Did not send");
          }
          return status;
        }),
        retryWhen((errs) =>
          errs.pipe(
            delay(1000),
            tap((err) => console.log)
          )
        )
      )
      .subscribe({
        next: console.log,
        error: console.error,
        complete: () => {
          console.log("complete", task);
        }
      });
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log("error in subject subscribe");
  }
);

subject.next("test1");
subject.next("test2");
subject.next("test3");
subject.next("test4");
```

Thanks!

```js
const { Subject, bindNodeCallback } = rxjs;
const { tap, retryWhen, delay } = rxjs.operators;

function fakeSend(
  task,
  cb
) {
  console.log("fakesend", task);

  setTimeout(() => {
    const hasError = Math.random() < 0.5;
    const res = Math.random() < 0.5;
    console.log(hasError ? "hasError" : `responding with ${res}`);
    if (hasError) {
      return cb(new Error("error"));
    }
    return cb(null, res);
  }, 100);
}

const boundSend = bindNodeCallback(fakeSend);
const subject = new Subject();

subject.subscribe(
  (task) => {
    boundSend(task)
      .pipe(
        tap((status) => {
          console.log('tap');
          if (!status) {
            throw new Error("Did not send");
          }
          return status;
        }),
        retryWhen((errs) =>
          errs.pipe(
            delay(1000),
            tap((err) => console.log)
          )
        )
      )
      .subscribe({
        next: console.log,
        error: console.error,
        complete: () => {
          console.log("complete", task);
        }
      });
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log("error in subject subscribe");
  }
);

subject.next("test1");
subject.next("test2");
subject.next("test3");
subject.next("test4");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.6.2/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

#### edit

I got it working with this:

```js
subject.subscribe(
  (task) => {
    of(task).pipe(
      mergeMap((v) => boundSend(v)),
      tap((val) => {
        if (!val) throw new Error("Did not send");
      }),
      retryWhen((errs) => errs.pipe(delay(300)))
    ).subscribe();
  });
```

However, I don't understand why this doesn't work:

```js
subject
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((task) => boundSend(task)),
    tap((val) => {
      if (!val) throw new Error("Did not send");
    }),
    retryWhen((errs) => errs.pipe(delay(300)))
  )
  .subscribe();
```

### Edit2

Well. I guess this explains it:  https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1401

Here I was thinking it was because I'm an RX noob :/

Comment: I made your script runable in a local snippet

Comment: Makes it easier for someone to copy snippet to answer if they have a solution for you

Comment: @AdrianBrand That's awesome, thank you!

Comment: It is best to have the associated code for a question stored on StackOverflow rather than an external site. Hopefully we will get a TypeScript snippet support soon. Hint hint StackOverflow devs! Maybe even with npm support so we don't have to rely on CDNs.

Comment: @AdrianBrand yea, I totally get it. I keep forgetting that was added :). Thanks again!

Comment: You shouldn't see a nested subscription in rxjs. I have had a boozy lunch and not up to thinking in rxjs at the moment but might look at it tomorrow if someone else hasn't chimed in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try to use the `new Observable` constructor rather than `bindNodeCallback` if you want to be able to retry the *callback-based* function in case of errors via `retryWhen`operator. Some details follow.

First, you can create an Observable out of a *callback-based* function using the `new Observable` constructor like this

```
function newSend(task: string) {
  return new Observable(
    (subscriber: Subscriber<string>): TeardownLogic => {
      fakeSend(task, (err: Error | null, result?: string) => {
        if (err) {
          subscriber.error(err);
        } else {
          subscriber.next(result);
          subscriber.complete();
        }
      });
    }
  );
}
```

The function `newSend` returns an Observable which internally calls `fakeSend` and the emits a results or errors depending on the parameters received by the callback passed to `fakeSend`.

Now that we have a way to create an Observable wrapping our *callback-based* function, we can use `mergeMap` to create a stream of results of the callback out of the stream of notifications generated via the **subject**, like this

```
subject
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((task) => {
      return newSend(task);
    })
  )
  .subscribe(
    (data) => console.log("Notification", data),
    (error) => {
      console.log("Error in final subscription", error);
    },
    () => console.log("DONE")
  );

subject.next("test1");
subject.next("test2");
subject.next("test3");
subject.next("test4");

subject.complete();  // added just to show that the complete function of the subscriber can be invoked
```

If we execute the above code, we see that the subscription on the **subject** logs all successful calls to `fakeSend` until an error is encountered, at which points it logs an error and terminates (see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-8w9aa7?file=index.ts)).

We can then add the `retryWhen` operator to actually retry in case of error in the `fakeSend` callback like this

```
subject
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((task) => {
      return newSend(task).pipe(
        retryWhen((errs) =>
          errs.pipe(
            delay(1000),
            tap((err) => console.log("Retry", err.message))
          )
        )
      );
    })
  )
```

At this point our logic is complete. Any time the `fakeSend` callback is invoked with an error the `retryWhen` operator will make sure a new call to `fakeSend`, with the same parameters, is performed. The complete code can be seen in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-yqv73w?file=index.ts).

**WHY IT DOES NOT WORK WITH** `bindNodeCallback`

The reason is that the implementation of `bindNodeCallback` uses internally an `AsyncSubject` which caches the last result and replays it at subsequent subscriptions. So, if the *callback-based* function errors and the `retryWhen` operator subscribes again, then the subscription generates again the same error, starting an infinite loop. This can be seen [in the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-yqv73w?file=index.ts) if you substitute `newSend(task)` with `boundSend(task)` (lines 46 and 47)

Comment: Thank you for such an thorough and thorough explanation. Truly awesome of you.

Comment: It was an interesting problem that helped me as well